# java.lang.NullPointerException on twitter.showUser()

Tags: android, twitter, nullpointerexception

I added screen names an string array and I want to populate other arrays with realnames,followersCount.When I login, occuring an nullpointerexception on line twitter.showUser(arrayKullaniciAdi[i]);Where I'm doing wrong?

Note:There isnt a problem on Login process.

Code:

```
User user;
String[] arrayKullaniciAdi = new String[] { "myscreenname", "herscreenname"}

 private void loginToTwitter() {


        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {

                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));


                try {

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayKullaniciAdi.length; i++) {


//ERROR İS HERE
                        user = twitter.showUser(arrayKullaniciAdi[i]);
                        arrayKullaniciAdi[i] = user.getScreenName();
                        arrayGercekAd[i] = user.getName();
                        arrayTakipciSayisi[i] = user.getFollowersCount();
                        arrayResim[i] = user.getProfileImageURL();
                    }

                    lv1.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, arrayKullaniciAdi));

                }// try

                catch (TwitterException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

        }


        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayKullaniciAdi.length; i++) {    
//AND HERE

                user = twitter.showUser(arrayKullaniciAdi[i].toString());
                arrayKullaniciAdi[i] = user.getScreenName();
                arrayGercekAd[i] = user.getName();
                arrayTakipciSayisi[i] = user.getFollowersCount();
                arrayResim[i] = user.getProfileImageURL();
            }

        }

        catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        lv1.setAdapter(new Adapter(this, arrayKullaniciAdi));


    }
```

ERRORS:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.tf.LoginActivity.loginToTwitter(LoginActivity.java:291)
at com.example.tf.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:341)
```

Comment: Did you debug to see what's null?

Comment: Hey user    null.Why it is null?

Comment: arrayKullaniciAdi is null?

Comment: No.arrayKullaniciAdi String[106]  (id=831986916848)

Comment: Is `User` your class? then try initializing it as `User user = new User();` instead of `User user;`

Comment: No.User is twitter4j.User class.it should work on this form but it is null    

http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/2.1.1/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html

showUser(java.lang.String screenName) 
          Returns extended information of a given user, specified by screen name as per the required id parameter below.